# Как получить из строки в формате `JSON` собственно `JSON` объект?

Tags: node.js, json, javascript

Как получить из строки в формате `JSON` собственно `JSON` объект? То есть я сохраняю `JSON` объект в файл и потом его загружаю, но он уже не работает, как `JSON` объект, например, невозможно использовать обращения по ключам.

Как его обратно превратить в `JSON` объект? Пробовал делать `JSON.stringify`, но он ломал вложенные ключи, присваивая им `id`'шки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` создаёт JSON-строку из объекта. Тебе надо прямо противоположное - `JSON.parse()`.
[Учи матчасть, студент.](http://learn.javascript.ru/json#json-stringify-и-json-parse)

Comment: Вмдимо, косяк был в другом месте кода, переписал по-новой, и теперь всё работает, раньше parse делал каждому элементу свой индекс.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = '{"id":1, "value":2}';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```